# Per Post Type Revision Numbers

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type, revisions

In `wp-config.php` you're able to change how WordPress deals with [post revisions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Post_Revisions). Specifically you're able to turn them off or specify a max number of revisions.

I'd like to be able to set a max number or revisions on a post type basis.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Remove the action `'wp_save_post_revision'` from `'pre_post_update'`. It is set per default in `wp-includes/default-filters.php` with the default priority (10).
2. Add your own function to this hook. You get the `$post_ID` as parameter, so [detecting the post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_type) is easy.
3. In your callback copy the code from `wp_save_post_revision()` but use the constant `WP_POST_REVISIONS` for the post type `post` only, and use different values for other post types. Not sure if it is possible to pass extra values in `register_post_type()` …

Comment: This is the winner: https://gist.github.com/2884090 You do have to roll your own revision meta box, however. The built in one still uses `WP_POST_REVISIONS`.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but it's not as simple as changing the `WP_POST_REVISIONS` property in the `wp-config.php`. This is possible by adding a filter to the 'wp_insert_post_data'.

Adding a filter is done like this:

```
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'my_insert_post_data');

function my_insert_post_data($data , $postarr) {
  // Check the revision stuff
  return $data;
}
```

Comment: Except `wp_insert_post_data` does not take care of deleting extra revisions, which is what I want to avoid.

Comment: Upvoted. @ChristopherDavis Completely understand what you're after. On the other hand, this could be extended to _maybe_ handle it...

Answer (score 0):

after 11 years of the question, today I stumbled upon this question and here is my solution:

```
// keep 10 revisions for only posts.
// /wp-includes/revision.php:621
// filter: wp_{$post->post_type}_revisions_to_keep
add_filter('wp_post_revisions_to_keep', 'postRevisionsToKeep');
function postRevisionsToKeep(): int
{
    return 10;
}
```